# ng-repeat vs ng-options which is best for me

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

i have to display the JSON data in drop down list ,for that i have two options one of the options is By using ng-repeat and other one is ng-options.

ng-repeat code :

in html file :

```
<select>
<option ng-repeat="prod in testAccounts" value="{{prod.id}}">{{prod.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and in script file:

```
$http.get('document.json').success(function (data) 
{
    $scope.testAccounts = angular.fromJson(data);
 }
```

and other one ng-options :

in html file :

```
<select ng-model="selectedTestAccount" ng-options="c as c.name for c in testAccounts1"></select>
```

in script file:

```
$http.get('document.json').success(function (data) 
{
    $scope.testAccounts1 = data;
    $scope.selectedTestAccount = $scope.testAccounts1[0];
}
```

Now i want to know which one is best for my project to improve the performance .Any guidelines please .

Comment: I think that ng-options, because that is meant to be used in cases like this.

Comment: I haven't posted it as an answer if you want I can.\

Comment: yes please ,please provide i am waiting for answer @Mritunjay

Comment: is it enough "meant to be used in cases like this" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that ng-options, because that is meant to be used in cases like this.

[Angularjs Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select):-

ngOptions provides an iterator facility for the  element which should be used instead of ngRepeat when you want the select model to be bound to a non-string value. This is because an option element can only be bound to string values at present.

Answer (score 1):

As far as performance is regarded, I think you should use your own directive that will handle it.

ng-options puts every element in $watch => gets really slow if the list contains hundreds elements

ng-repeat will be slow to be rendered.

You should then prefer using your own directive, and build your html into it

Answer (score 0):

The code below (also in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GjGaKb2nYkRlMCqt2J6T)) shows no difference even when the model is bound to a non-string value (an arithmetic code) *except* for the initialization where the approach with `ng-repeat` fails to display the default value (or maybe there's a workaround for that as well). After a value is chosen the behavior is the same:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>making choices </title>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='theApp' ng-controller='TheController as ctl'>
    <div ng-controller='TheController as ctl'>
      Select your favorite fruit:
      <select ng-model='ctl.selectedFruitCode'>
        <option ng-repeat='fruit in ctl.fruits' ng-value='fruit.code'>{{fruit.label}}</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      Selected fruit is: <tt>{{ctl.getSelectedFruit().label}}</tt> (from code: {{ctl.selectedFruitCode}})
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller='TheController as ctl'>
      Select your favorite fruit:
      <select ng-model='ctl.selectedFruitCode'
              ng-options='c.code as c.label for c in ctl.fruits'>
      </select>
      <br/>
      Selected fruit is: <tt>{{ctl.getSelectedFruit().label}}</tt> (from code: {{ctl.selectedFruitCode}})
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     angular.module('theApp', [])
            .controller('TheController', [function() {
              var self = this;
              self.fruits = {};
              self.fruits = [{label: 'Apples'   , code:0},
                             {label: 'Bananas'  , code:1},
                             {label: 'Peach'    , code:2},
                             {label: 'Apricot'  , code:3}];
              self.selectedFruitCode = self.fruits[0].code;
              self.getSelectedFruit = function() {
                for (var i = 0 ; i < self.fruits.length ; i++) {
                  if (self.fruits[i].code==self.selectedFruitCode)
                    return self.fruits[i];
                }
              };
            }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```