# Binding preselected value from model into angular drop down list

Tags: angularjs

I have looked at AngularJS documentation- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions
But unable to figure out how to preselect a value in the drop-down list based on model definition.

Please take a look at this Plunker, HTML view should display 'Gram' as selected value in the "Unit Drop down list" but for some reason it shows blank value as selected.
Please suggest what i am doing wrong here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/5gO0bjXOx2mlPXgo7m4u?p=preview

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myTestApp', []);
app.controller('myTestCtrl', myTestCtrl);
function myTestCtrl() {
 var vm = this;
 vm.message = "test"

vm.data = {
  "units": [{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Gram"
  }, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Litre"
  }, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Pound"
  }]
 };


vm.currentIngredient = {
"ingredientId": 1,
"ingredientName": "Salt",
"description": "Sea Salt.",
"unit": {
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Gram"
 },
  "status": true
};

vm.selectedUnit = vm.currentIngredient;
}
```

Below is my View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"> </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body ng-app='myTestApp' ng-controller='myTestCtrl as vm'>
   {{vm.message}}
 <div>...</div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputUnit">Unit:</label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedUnit" ng-options="u.id as u.name for u in vm.data.units"></select>
   </div>
  </div>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: ``selectedUnit`` in view null as it is available as ``vm.selectedUnit`` which has object as a value but trying to bind the unit.id to this object value. So if you use  ``vm.selectedUnit.unit.id`` then it should work.

Comment: I tried using this in my View - vm.selectedUnit.unit.id. But it still defaults to blank as selected in the Unit DDL.

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested in the comments, you are not bound to your property of `vm.selectedUnit`, you are bound to `$scope.selectedUnit`, which is not the same thing.  Also, you are not pre-selecting a value that matches the dropdown hierarchy correctly.  There are two changes that should be made to make this work.

In the HTML, change to `vm.selectedUnit`:

```
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selectedUnit" ng-options="u.id as u.name for u in vm.data.units"></select>
```

In the JavaScript, change the preselect:

```
 vm.selectedUnit =  vm.currentIngredient.unit.id;
```

Forked Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/i5EyTvekhJ75yj903qrB?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

I have done with some changes hope you like my work here is my plunker code

my Html Code is here...

```
<select>
       <option ng-repeat="units in vm.units">
        {{units.name}}
       </option>

</select>
```

and app.js with changes is like...

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myTestApp',[]);

app.controller('myTestCtrl',myTestCtrl);

function myTestCtrl(){
  var vm =this;
  vm.message="test"


        vm.data = {
            "units": [
                { "id": 0, "name": "Gram" },
                { "id": 1, "name": "Litre" },
                { "id": 2, "name": "Pound" }
            ]
        };


        vm.currentIngredient = {
            "ingredientId": 1,
            "ingredientName": "Salt",
            "description": "Sea Salt.",
            "unit": { "id": 0, "name": "Gram" },
            "status": true
        };

        // vm.selectedUnit =  vm.currentIngredient;
         vm.units= vm.data.units;


}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/E7JchKQraWlqIjqIBqZs?p=preview

Comment: while this *might* work, your code appears to omit the `ng-model` entirely, and only happens to have a "preselected" value because it is the first in the list.  You also have removed `ng-options` and used `ng-repeat` instead, which is not intended for use within a `<select>` element.  Overall, this a poor answer to the question.

Comment: yeah no doubt but as i already said "i have done with some changes" and also according to #user3400087 question he wants to display gram as selected value and i have done the same. i don't think there is any reason that you downvote my answer.

Comment: I want to use ng-options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483903/ng-repeat-vs-ng-options-which-is-best-for-me

Comment: Also, it works as desired if I use -**track by u.id**. But I was trying to figure out  to make it work without using this. Any inputs?

Comment: @PardeepJain actually, you didn't display anything as the "selected value", since you have no `ng-model`, this select box is **never** bound to anything at all.  and if you were to add `ng-model` and then log the value of that model variable in the controller, you would find it's `undefined`.  This *is not* a solution that is viable.

Comment: yes i agree i have't use ng-model but no doubt its a valid solution. you can consider this one as alternate. Assuming so i answer to this question. user follow to this method or not its his choice i gave him one alternate.