# not able to access object property angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML:

```
  <select ng-model="outlet">
        <option ng-repeat="outlet in outlets" value='{{outlet}}'>
 {{outlet.name}}</option></select>
```

Now, In my controller:

```
console.log(outlet)
console.log(outlet._id)
var selectedoutlet = {"_id":"554c930c79d26026307a5a9d","name":"Model Town","city":"Default"};
console.log(selectedoutlet);
console.log(selectedoutlet._id)
```

Output:

```
{"_id":"554c930c79d26026307a5a9d","name":"Model Town","city":"Default"}
 undefined
 {_id: "554c930c79d26026307a5a9d", name: "Model Town", city: "Default"}
 554c930c79d26026307a5a9d
```

Why is it that I can not access properties of outlet object?How do I fix this?
I can see it is because my object properties are strings but how do I get around this? I certainly do not want to loop and match string. I just need to access object properties.

Comment: Why not use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-options to have the model as json of the selected element, in case of using ng-repeat, the model is bind to the option value as a string. Here is how it should be:

```
<select ng-model="outlet" ng-options="outlet.name for outlet in outlets" ng-change="display()">
 </select>
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483903/ng-repeat-vs-ng-options-which-is-best-for-me) for further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

if your outlet variable is a string instead of object, the best way to convert to object is using `JSON.parse(outlet)`